# Get whole Information of JavaServer Page -- Web Scraping

Tags: jsp, url, web-scraping, inputstream

I'm trying to connect to an URL Homepage with `java.net.URLConnection` and just get the websource code as a `String`. With my webbrowser the homepage is completly loaded (takes some time) and a list is filled with some items (in SourceCode: `simpleListItem.jsp` (JavaServer Page)).

If I connect via my Java application and print the `String`, this items are not part of my string. It is like my application is streaming the code and is done, before the list is filled.

Webpage sourcecode via browser is structured like this:

```
 start hits.jsp
     start simpleListItem.jsp 
     start simpleListItem.jsp 
       ...
     start simpleListItem.jsp
 end hits.jsp
```

Webpage sourcecode via Java application is structured like this:

```
 start hits.jsp
 send hits.jsp
```

How do I get all informations of an URL? All JavaServerPages-ScriptElements?

Hope my Question is clear :D

**EDIT:**

With your help I think I can specify my question now ;)
Like [home](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834362/home) said, the problem is, that I want to get informations of an webpage that is added to the page by JavaScript, **after** the page is sent. So in my example, I can't get the informations of `simpleListItem.jsp`. My Java method just connects to the URL and prints the Output, see below:

```
 public void readURL(String url) {
    URL mURL = new URL(url);
    URLConnection mConnection = mURL.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                mConnection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

So with that, I won't get the fully loaded page. I need something like, an option to read the page when it es fully loaded.

Thanks Guys!!

Comment: "*.jsp addons"? Please figure out what the proper terminology for what you're asking is.

Comment: I've added some details to improve my question. And I'm sorry I didn't use the "proper terminology". It's my first time I'm working with php and javascript, so I've thought my question was clear.

Comment: So it is about PHP/JavaScript? Btw: we cannot answer your question as you did not provide any source code. Consider that a) you might have to submit parameters to your JSP, 2) the page might use JavaScript to load data **after** the page has been sent, 3) etc etc

Comment: I do not have any source code yet. Only a little Java application, that connects to an URL and prints the response of the inputstream `connection.getInputStream()`. I think the problem is, that the page works like your 2). It uses JavaScript to load data after the page has sent. Is there a way to get this post displayed data?

Sry once again. It is hard to ask a proper question if you're not 100% into the topic. But thanks for your quick replies! :)

Comment: Please put your source code sample and what is "all information" give an example.

Comment: `"the problem is, that I want to get informations of an webpage that is added to the page by JavaScript"`: You can't. Not with just Java out of the box. You'll need some fancy library, and I don't know of one.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm some steps further, although I don't have a solution. I'm currently working on my problem with `htmlunit`. Still stuck loading the JavaScript parts proberly.. If I have a solution I will post it.

Comment: htmlunit didn't work either, but finally I found a solution see at the bottom. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) was the key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was searching is called "**Web Scraping**". I tried different libraries and languages like JavaScript and Python ([PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/),..). I had a big struggle installing them, especially Zombie.js on my Windows 7 PC. I finally got it to work, but it did not load the dynamic content of the page. Totally desperate I found:

**[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)** !!!!!!!!!!

JSoup is a Java library. So all i need to install, was to copy the library into my Java Project. It works perfect! All dynamic content is loaded and I can use cookies to avoid "Session expired" Errors. If you familiar with Java, I can just recommend JSoup for you.

I post some beginning code for you:

```
try {
   // Extract jSessionId from startURL for Cookies
   String startURL =  "xxxxx";
   Document startPage = Jsoup.connect(startURL)
                             .userAgent("Mozilla")
                             .get();
   Element jSessionElement = startPage.getElementById("jSessionElementID");
   JSessionID = getJessionIDfromElement(jSessionElement);  // own method

   // Connect to page of interest
   String resultURL = "xxxxxxxxxx";
   Document resultPage = Jsoup.connect(resultURL)
                              .timeout(10000)
                              .cookie("JSESSIONID", JSessionID)
                              .get();

   // use html parser of JSoup to extract content

} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, I hope this helps if someone is desperate like I was.

Comment: Instead of `JSessionID = getJessionIDfromElement(jSessionElement);`, ----------------- were you going -- --to write: `JSessionID = getjSessionIDfromElement(jSessionElement);`?